# mongodb : get all users

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript

how do i edit this function of mine to get all users ? I have just started learning async await and i am having hard time learning how to get the request body.
here is my function :

```
export const get: Operation = async (
  req: express.Request,
  res: express.Response
) => {
  commonUtility.showRequestParam(req);


  let users: db.IUserDocument[] = [];
  try {
    // Describe data acquisition and registration from mongoDB here.
    users = await UserModel.find()
      .then(data => {
        return data;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
      });
  } catch (err) {
    // Error.
    api.responseError(res, err);
  }

  if (users.length < 1) {
    // this case is 404 ???
    api.responseJSON(res, 200, []);
  }
};
```

here is my user model:

```
export const usersSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  BaseFields
});

export const UserModel = mongoose.model<db.IUserDocument>('Users', usersSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `.then` when using `async` and `await`

```
export const get: Operation = async (
  req: express.Request,
  res: express.Response
) => {
  commonUtility.showRequestParam(req);
  let users: db.IUserDocument[] = [];
  try {
    users = await UserModel.find();
    api.responseJSON(res, 200,users);
  } catch (err) {
    // Error.
    api.responseError(res, err);
  }  
};
```

Read more about async await here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: thank you so much for replying , I want to know how do i get back just the id and the username ? how do i filter my response ?

Comment: Use a projection operator for it. `UserModel.find({},{_id:1, username:1})`. Getting only required fields which we want.

Comment: i posted a new question , that I think you can really help me with if you can